# How to add a conditional to jQuery .hover()

Tags: jquery, hover, conditional-statements

I want to use the jQuery hover function and can do so with no problem.

```
 $(".tag").hover(function() { $(this).addClass("tag-over"); }, function() { $(this).removeClass("tag-over"); });
```

However in some circumstances I will have already added the `tag-over` class due to a `click` event, but I don't want it remove when the user removes the mouse.

How do I only perform the addClass() and rmeoveClass() if the `tag-over` class is not already attached to the element.

Please let me know if that explanation is no good.

Comment: perhaps `hasClass('classname')` ??

Comment: Actually this should be pretty easy ... after writing the question it seems trivial.

Comment: perhaps with gloabl external variable??

Comment: Or having two class names with the same css using one for the hover and one for the click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually want to probably have a different selector for the click event: `tag-focus` or something like that.  That way your element can have both classes and it won't matter, much simpler to keep track of.

Comment: Yes I think I am going to have to use this method.

Comment: Note that you probably don't even have to change the CSS much, just make the selector: `.tag-over, .tag-focus {`

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question, you can use [:not()](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/), which I think would be the best of dealing with this.

```
$(".tag:not(.tag-over)").hover(function() { $(this).addClass("tag-over"); }, function() { $(this).removeClass("tag-over"); });
```

Comment: This will only work if the element has the `tag-over` class on page load, not after a click.

Answer (score 2):

I think something like this should do it:

```
$('.tag').hover(function() {
    var $this = $(this);

    if ($this.hasClass('tag-over')) {
        $this.data('tag-over-existed', true);
    } else {
        $this.addClass('tag-over');
    }
}, function() {
    var $this = $(this);

    if (!$this.data('tag-over-existed')) { // i.e. if we added the class ourselves
        $this.removeClass('tag-over');
    }

    $this.removeData('tag-over-existed');
});
```

This uses the [`data`](http://api.jquery.com/data) method to store information about a particular element.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you try to add class `tagover` for click event and `tag-over` for hover event?

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Not elegant solution though [here](http://jsfiddle.net/V7DFd/).

Bad thing about it, it adds `click` class to check.

```
$('.tag').hover(
    function (){
        $(this).addClass("tag-over"); 
    },
    function (){
        if(!$(this).hasClass('clicked')){
            $(this).removeClass("tag-over"); 
        }
    }
).click(function (){
            $(this).addClass('click');
        })
```